# Some troubles with bash script to update CSV

Tags: bash, shell, csv

The problem is that it is not possible to process the title field correctly if it consists of several words separated by a comma.

> Bash Task 1
>
> Company ABC has uncontrolled process of employee’s accounts creation. Currently process means adding names, email and other personal data manually to the `accounts.csv` file without any rules. Department head has decided to improve it based on the naming convention implementation. Good idea for newcomers, but what to do with current user’s list? You have been asked to help. Could you please develop automated way (Bash script) and create new `accounts_new.csv` file based on current `accounts.csv` and below.

Need to update column name. Name format: first letter of name/surname uppercase and all other letters lowercase.
Need to update column email with domain @abc. Email format: first letter from name and full surname, lowercase. If two email addresses are otherwise identical, they should be disambiguated by adding the value of `location_id` before the `@` sign.

The script should have the name `task1.sh`.

Path to `accounts.csv` file should be as argument to the script.

Definition of done: Developed Bash script which automatically creates `accounts_new.csv` and updates columns `name` and `email` based on the rules above.

Trouble Data from `accounts.csv`:

```
id,location_id,name,title,email,department
3,2,Brenda Brown,Director, Second Career Services,,
4,3,Howard Lader,Manager, Senior Counseling,,
5,4,Kimberly Pesavento,Commercial Director,,
18,11,Dave Genesy,Head of Office,,
22,14,Andres Espinoza,Manager, Commanding Officer,,
```

Must be like this:

```
  *what I need* - '3,2,Brenda Brown,"Director, Second Career Services",bbrown@abc.com,\n',                 
  what I have -  '3,2,Brenda Brown,Director,bbrown@abc.com,\n',
  *what I need* -  '4,3,Howard Lader,"Manager, Senior Counseling",hlader@abc.com,\n',
  what I have -  '4,3,Howard Lader,Manager,hlader@abc.com,\n',
 * what I need* -  '5,4,Kimberly Pesavento,Commercial director,kpesavento@abc.com,\n',
  what I have - '5,4,Kimberly Pesavento,Commercial Director,kpesavento@abc.com,\n',
  *what I need* - '18,11,Dave Genesy,Head of office,dgenesy11@abc.com,\n',             
  what I have - '18,11,Dave Genesy,Head of Office,dgenesy11@abc.com,\n',
  *what I need* - '22,14,Andres Espinoza,"Manager, Commanding Officer",aespinoza@abc.com,\n',                        
  what I have - '22,14,Andres Espinoza,Manager,aespinoza@abc.com,\n',
```

```
#!/bin/bash
function format_name() {
    local first_name last_name
    # Разбиение полного имени на имя и фамилию, приведение к нижнему регистру
    read -r first_name last_name <<<"$(echo "$1" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')"
    # Преобразование первой буквы имени и фамилии к верхнему регистру
    first_name=$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<<"${first_name:0:1}")${first_name:1}
    last_name=$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<<"${last_name:0:1}")${last_name:1}

    if [[ $last_name == *-* ]]; then
        hyphen_pos=$(expr index "$last_name" "-")
        last_name=${last_name:0:hyphen_pos}$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<<"${last_name:$hyphen_pos:1}")${last_name:$hyphen_pos+1}
    fi
    echo "$first_name $last_name"
}

function is_exception() {
    local word=$1
    local exceptions=("Office" "for" "and" "the" "of" "new") # Список исключений
    for exception in "${exceptions[@]}"; do
        if [[ $word == $exception ]]; then
            return 0 # Слово является исключением
        fi
    done
    return 1 # Слово не является исключением
}

function format_title() {
    local title="$1"
    local formatted_title=""
    local word

    # Преобразование каждого слова в заголовке
    for word in $title; do
        if is_exception "$word"; then
            # Преобразование слова-исключения к нижнему регистру
            formatted_title+=" $(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<<"$word")"
        else
            # Преобразование первой буквы слова к верхнему регистру
            formatted_title+=" $(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<<"${word:0:1}")${word:1}"
        fi
    done
    echo "${formatted_title:1}" # Удаление начального пробела
}

function generate_email() {
    local alias=$1
    local location_id=$2
    local domain="@abc.com"
    email=${alias}

    # Добавление location_id, если адрес уже встречался
    if [[ ${alias_counts[$alias]} -gt 1 ]]; then
        email=${email}${location_id}
    fi

    email=${email}${domain}
    echo "$email"
}

function create_email_alias() {
    local first_name="${1%% *}"
    local last_name="${1#* }"

    alias=$(echo "${first_name:0:1}${last_name}" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
    echo "$alias"
}

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <accounts.csv>"
    exit 1
fi

declare -A alias_counts
alias_array=()

input_file=$1
output_file="accounts_new.csv"

read -r header <"$input_file"
echo "$header" >"$output_file"

skip_header=true

while IFS=',' read -r id location_id name title email department; do
    if $skip_header; then
        skip_header=false
        continue
    fi

    alias=$(create_email_alias "$name")
    alias_array+=("$alias")
    ((alias_counts[$alias]++))
done <"$input_file"

skip_header=true

while IFS=',' read -r id location_id name title email department; do
    if $skip_header; then
        skip_header=false
        continue
    fi

    # Форматирование имени и заголовка
    formatted_name=$(format_name "$name")
    formatted_title=$(format_title "$title")
    formatted_email=$(generate_email "$(create_email_alias "$name")" "$location_id")

    # Запись отформатированных данных в выходной файл
    echo "$id,$location_id,$formatted_name,$formatted_title,$formatted_email,$department" >>"$output_file"
done <"$input_file"

echo "Processing done. $output_file created."
```

Comment: I'm guessing that `awk` is not allowed since this sounds like a homework assignment specifically to learn `bash`. Is that a fair statement, OP?

Comment: In general, I wouldn't advise bash for this at all -- Python has a CSV parser built-in and it'll handle everything involved correctly out-of-the-box.

Comment: Your code doesn't contain a second D. Genesy so there is no way to test the `location_id` requirement with this data. Frankly, I didn't understand what it meant until now. (The email address `dgenesy11`. includes `11` from the `location_id` field, presumably because there was another `dgenesy` in data we cannot see.)

Comment: BTW, `function funcname() {` merges the 1980s ksh syntax `function funcname {` and the POSIX sh syntax `funcname() {` in a way that's incompatible with _both_ 1980s ksh and POSIX (and doesn't offer the special behavior that `function` provides in ksh, where its use has some impact on which variables are considered function-local). Better to stick with the POSIX form.

Comment: You start CSV contains several errors. In this image you can see what you should change https://i.imgur.com/fHEI5gl.png And here the two versions of the file https://gist.github.com/aborruso/01ab1c96258c871c8ec317513199d5a1/revisions

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a shell read loop for this, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Here is a possible start:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
    NR == 1 {
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            tags2fldNrs[$i] = i
            fldNrs2tags[i] = $i
        }
        badFldNrsBeg = tags2fldNrs["title"]
        nf = NF
        next
    }
    {
        badFldNrsEnd = badFldNrsBeg + (NF - nf)

        fldNr = 0
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            if ( (i <= badFldNrsBeg) || (badFldNrsEnd < i) ) {
                vals[++fldNr] = $i
            }
            else {
                vals[fldNr] = vals[fldNr] FS $i
            }
        }
        vals[badFldNrsBeg] = "\"" vals[badFldNrsBeg] "\""

        nameFldNr = tags2fldNrs["name"]
        emailFldNr = tags2fldNrs["email"]

        n = split(vals[nameFldNr],name," ")
        vals[emailFldNr] = tolower(substr(name[1],1,1) name[n]) "@abc.com"

        for ( i=1; i<=nf; i++ ) {
            printf "%s%s", vals[i], (i<nf ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
' "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh accounts.csv
3,2,Brenda Brown,"Director, Second Career Services",bbrown@abc.com,
4,3,Howard Lader,"Manager, Senior Counseling",hlader@abc.com,
5,4,Kimberly Pesavento,"Commercial Director",kpesavento@abc.com,
18,11,Dave Genesy,"Head of Office",dgenesy@abc.com,
22,14,Andres Espinoza,"Manager, Commanding Officer",aespinoza@abc.com,
```

You should do whatever you need to do to ensure the email addresses are unique, at least add code to ensure that ANY field that contains commas or double quotes gets enclosed in double quotes and any double quote inside a field gets doubled to escape it. See [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk) for more information.

FWIW I wrote the above to be a useful learning experience for the OP on how to approach such problems in general with awk, but if we can make assumptions about the input always looking like the OP posted then it could just be:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    NR == 1 { nf = NF; next }
    {
        d=(NF-nf); $4="\""$4; $(4+d)=$(4+d)"\""
        split($3,n," ")
        $(NF-1) = tolower(substr(n[1],1,1) n[2])"@abc.com"
    }
1' accounts.csv
3,2,Brenda Brown,"Director, Second Career Services",bbrown@abc.com,
4,3,Howard Lader,"Manager, Senior Counseling",hlader@abc.com,
5,4,Kimberly Pesavento,"Commercial Director",kpesavento@abc.com,
18,11,Dave Genesy,"Head of Office",dgenesy@abc.com,
22,14,Andres Espinoza,"Manager, Commanding Officer",aespinoza@abc.com,
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I’ll try to test this option, it already looks much better than everything I had. Only quotes are needed only for the title field if it contains several positions separated by commas. I'll try to do this. Thanks again

Comment: Mind, I firmly disagree with that "bad practice" assertion and the contents of the link used to (purportedly) defend it.

Comment: (Mind, I respect Stephane, and nothing he asserts is untrue -- but the fact that people often do inefficient things inside a loop when they could instead replace the loop outright doesn't make `while read` loops bad practice; it merely makes _their inappropriate use_ bad practice)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy We may have to agree to disagree on that one. An awk script, for example, will be faster, briefer, simpler, and usually more portable than a bash while-read loop just for manipulating text. I'm not saying there aren't other things you could do in bash than write a while-read loop and I agree it's the *inappropriate use* that's bad practice, I'm just saying that manipulating text is one example of such inappropriate use. I would honestly be very interested to see an example where a bash while-read loop to manipulate text is in some way better than, say, an awk script though.

Comment: Manipulating text is a place where awk shines -- you'll get no argument from me on that. The places where a native bash loop is more appropriate are those where external tools need to be invoked inside the loop; _that's_ a place where awk is ill-suited.

Comment: 100% agree with that, but that's not just manipulating text, it's sequencing calls to tools which is one of the jobs shells exist to perform. I'm talking about just manipulating text.

Comment: Right. If the assertion were that a `while read` loop was bad practice _for places where the only operations being performed are textual manipulation_, I would have no objection at all. I suppose I'm reading the "to process text" in the title of the linked article as a weaker restriction than you are -- there are lots of kinds of processing; some of them involve calling out to external tools.

Comment: Got it. That IS the way I read that post but I can see how it could be interpreted otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I have not attempted to understand or debug your code. Here is a much simpler solution using *almost* only Bash builtins. Perhaps notice in particular the [parameter expansions.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

(I updated this to do duplicate detection for email addresses once I understood this requirement, and the quick fix I came up with uses several standard, but external utilities. It could be done in native Bash using associative arrays, like I guess your code already tries to do it.)

```
#!/bin/bash

capitalize () {
    local sep=''
    local field
    for field in "$@"; do
        field=${field,,}
        printf "%s%s" "$sep" "${field^}"
        sep=' '
    done
    printf '\n'
}

name2e () {
    printf '%0.1s%s\n' "${1,,}" "${2,,}"
}

get_duplicates () {
    cut -d, -f3 "$1" |
    sed 's/^\([^ ]\)[^ ]* /\1/' |
    tr A-Z a-z |
    sort |
    uniq -d
}

duplicates=$(get_duplicates "$1")
# A single newline in a string
nl='
'

first=true
while read -r line; do
    case $first in
        true) echo "$line"; first=false; continue;;
    esac
    for field in id location_id name; do
        printf -v "$field" '%s' "${line%%,*}"
        line=${line#"${!field}",}
    done
    for field in email department; do
        printf -v "$field" '%s' "${line##*,}"
        line=${line%",${!field}"}
    done
    case $email in
        '') email="$(name2e $name)";;
    esac
    case $nl$duplicates$nl in
        *"$nl$email$nl"*)
            email=$email$location_id;;
    esac
    case $line in
        *,*) title="\"$line\"";;
        *) title="$line";;
    esac
    printf "%i,%i,%s,%s,%s,%s\n" \
           "$id" "$location_id" "$(capitalize $name)" \
           "$title" "$email@abc.com" "$department"
done <"$1"
```

This chomps off two fields from the beginning and two from the end, and assumes that whatever remains is the title.

The only somewhat advanced technique here is the use of `printf -v "$field"` to create the variable whose name is the value of `$field`, and the indirect reference `${!field}` to go in the other direction.

I don't particularly like how I cut some corners by avoiding to quote the arguments to the functions, but it was a quick way to solve this with the limited data you provided. Hopefully it can at least inspire you to investigate more complex corner cases if you need to handle them (like "Right Hon. August Prinz von der Wienerschnitzel" and other illustrations of [Falsehoods Programmers Believe about Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)).

Demo: https://ideone.com/mNpGwb

Comment: Here I learn it's _das Schnitzel_ for the dish (and in Austria). https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schnitzel#German

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is *so much easier* with a language that has a CSV parser.

Here is a Ruby as an example:

```
ruby -r csv -e '
inp=CSV.parse($<.read)[1..]
dups=inp.map{|row| fn,ln=row[2].downcase.split; "#{fn[0]+ln}@abc.com"}.tally
puts CSV.generate{|csv|
    inp.each{|row| fn,ln=row[2].downcase.split
        email=dups["#{fn[0]+ln}@abc.com"]>1 ? 
            "#{fn[0]+ln+row[1]}@abc.com" : "#{fn[0]+ln}@abc.com"
        csv<<row[0..2]+[row[4].nil? ? row[3] : row[3..4].join(","), 
                            email,nil] 
        }
}' file
```

Prints (with OP example):

```
3,2,Brenda Brown,"Director, Second Career Services",bbrown@abc.com,
4,3,Howard Lader,"Manager, Senior Counseling",hlader@abc.com,
5,4,Kimberly Pesavento,Commercial Director,kpesavento@abc.com,
18,11,Dave Genesy,Head of Office,dgenesy@abc.com,
22,14,Andres Espinoza,"Manager, Commanding Officer",aespinoza@abc.com,
```

With tripleee's example:

```
3,2,Brenda Brown,"Director, Second Career Services",bbrown@abc.com,
4,3,Howard Lader,"Manager, Senior Counseling",hlader@abc.com,
5,4,Kimberly Pesavento,Commercial Director,kpesavento@abc.com,
18,11,Dave Genesy,Head of Office,dgenesy11@abc.com,
22,14,Andres Espinoza,"Manager, Commanding Officer",aespinoza@abc.com,
42,17,Danielle Genesy,Master of the Known Universe,dgenesy17@abc.com,
```

Python, Perl, or recent GNU Awk will be similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a CSV aware tools, you could use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.9.0/installing-miller/).

Your example CSV file is not properly formatted, see the image below (in the right the corrections). In your file the department info are in the email field.

[image]

Starting from yout example file

```
id,location_id,name,title,email,department
3,2,Brenda Brown,Director, Second Career Services,,
4,3,Howard Lader,Manager, Senior Counseling,,
5,4,Kimberly Pesavento,Commercial Director,,
18,11,Dave Genesy,Head of Office,,
22,14,Andres Espinoza,Manager, Commanding Officer,,
```

you can run

```
mlr --ho --csv --ragged unsparsify then put '$department=$email;$email="to@set"' then \
remove-empty-columns then put '$email=""' then \
put '
$title_department=sub(joinv([$title,$department],","),",$","");
$email=tolower(substr0($name,0,0).splita($name," ")[-1])."@abc.com"
' then \
cut -o -f id,location_id,name,title_department,email start.csv
```

to get

```
3,2,Brenda Brown,"Director, Second Career Services",bbrown@abc.com
4,3,Howard Lader,"Manager, Senior Counseling",hlader@abc.com
5,4,Kimberly Pesavento,Commercial Director,kpesavento@abc.com
18,11,Dave Genesy,Head of Office,dgenesy@abc.com
22,14,Andres Espinoza,"Manager, Commanding Officer",aespinoza@abc.com
```

Some notes:

- `--ragged`, because some line has different fields than the header line
- `$title_department=sub(joinv([$title,$department],","),",$","")` to join the two fields and the remove the comma a the end
- `$email=tolower(substr0($name,0,0).splita($name," ")[-1])."@abc.com"` to get the first char of name and concatenate it with last word (surname) in name field